# How to destroy tkiner window from another thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

I m sorry if it's a little confusing I will try to explain as simple as possible way, I have been trying to solve this threading issue for the past 2 days.

In short, what I m doing is running a big script on a separate thread once I hit the run button from the first screen, it reads data from the JSON file I have stored in the directory and Run a job.

Which gradually after completing steps increases the progress bar value and updates the label status from the run_script function.

And the error is after completing the first cycle when it comes back to first screen and if I run another job it doesnt work because of progressbar and label.

What I've tried so far is destroying the window from script_function and recreating it on the first screen. (2nd job worked but it didn't destroy the first job window, and after completing 2nd job it completely shutdown both windows)

without mttkinter, I got tcl run time error because I m trying to destroy the window from another thread.

```
from mttkinter import mtTkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
#other imports

window = Tk()

def screen1():
    ##show the screen with json data labels and buttons#
    window.geometry("1215x770")
    window.configure(bg="#FFFFFF")
    
    b0 = Button(window, text='Run job', command=do_something) #samplebutton

    window.resizable(False, False)
    window.mainloop()
    
def do_something():
    ##running big script with progressbar and status label.
    
    window.geometry("1215x770")
    window.configure(bg="#FFFFFF")
    
    progress = ttk.Progressbar(window, style='red.Horizontal.TProgressbar', orient=HORIZONTAL,
                               length=443, mode='determinate')
    progress.pack()
    
    label = Label("Completed tables 0/{totaltables}") #samplelabel
    label.pack()
    
    if data['foo'] == 'bar':
        threading.Thread(target=run_script, args=(arg1, arg2,)).start()  #run script in seperate thread this script also has a function that runs on multiple threads.
    
      
    window.resizable(False, False)
    window.mainloop()
    
def run_script(arg1, arg2):
    #running the script#
    for i in range(5): #running each i on new thread followed by starting and joining.
        print(i)
        
    #main problem#
    #once script finishes#
    
    response = messagebox.showinfo("Task", "Did something!")
    
    if response:
        screen1()
```

What is the possible way to accomplish this?
I want to keep running jobs without having to open the app again and again.
the script should be on a separate thread because if it's not the app goes not responding.
I want to keep showing the progress bar and status and once it's complete go back to the first screen.

How do I kill the main Tkinter thread after completing the first job?
or How do I destroy the Tkinter window from another thread?

Answer (score 1):

*If* you have a tcl/tk that is built with multithreading support, *and* you are using Python 3, you should be able to call tk functions from a second thread.

This is an [example program](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/python-examples/blob/main/tkinter/tk-threaded.pyw), where a second thread modifies widgets:

```
import os
import sys
import threading
import time
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkfont
import types

__version__ = "2022.02.02"
# Namespace for widgets that need to be accessed by callbacks.
widgets = types.SimpleNamespace()
# State that needs to be accessed by callbacks.
state = types.SimpleNamespace()


def create_widgets(root, w):
    """
    Create the window and its widgets.
    Arguments:
        root: the root window.
        w: SimpleNamespace to store widgets.
    """
    # General commands and bindings
    root.wm_title("tkinter threading v" + __version__)
    root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
    root.resizable(False, False)
    # First row
    tk.Label(root, text="Thread status: ").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
    w.runstatus = tk.Label(root, text="not running", width=12)
    w.runstatus.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ew")
    # Second row
    tk.Label(root, text="Timer: ").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
    w.counter = tk.Label(root, text="0 s")
    w.counter.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="ew")
    # Third row
    w.gobtn = tk.Button(root, text="Go", command=do_start)
    w.gobtn.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="ew")
    w.stopbtn = tk.Button(root, text="Stop", command=do_stop, state=tk.DISABLED)
    w.stopbtn.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="ew")


def initialize_state(s):
    """
    Initialize the global state.
    Arguments:
        s: SimpleNamespace to store application state.
    """
    s.worker = None
    s.run = False
    s.counter = 0


def worker():
    """
    Function that is run in a separate thread.
    This function *does* update tkinter widgets.  In Python 3, this should be
    safe if a tkinter is used that is built with threads.
    """
    # Initialization
    widgets.runstatus["text"] = "running"
    # Work
    while state.run:
        time.sleep(0.25)
        state.counter += 0.25
        widgets.counter["text"] = f"{state.counter:.2f} s"
    # Finalization
    state.counter = 0.0
    widgets.counter["text"] = f"{state.counter:g} s"
    widgets.runstatus["text"] = "not running"


def do_start():
    """Callback for the “Go” button"""
    widgets.gobtn["state"] = tk.DISABLED
    widgets.stopbtn["state"] = tk.NORMAL
    state.run = True
    state.worker = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    state.worker.start()


def do_stop():
    """Callback for the “Stop” button"""
    widgets.gobtn["state"] = tk.NORMAL
    widgets.stopbtn["state"] = tk.DISABLED
    state.run = False
    state.worker = None


# Main program starts here.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Detach from the command line on UNIX systems.
    if os.name == "posix":
        if os.fork():
            sys.exit()
    # Initialize global state
    initialize_state(state)
    # Create the GUI window.
    root = tk.Tk(None)
    # Set the font
    default_font = tkfont.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
    default_font.configure(size=12)
    root.option_add("*Font", default_font)
    create_widgets(root, widgets)
    root.mainloop()
```

Note how the worker thread monitors `state.run` and exits when it becomes `False`.

In general I find using multiple top-level windows confusing, so I don't use that pattern.
I would rather create a grid with rows of a progressbar and stop button for every thread.